Schnorr multisig
In Schnorr multi-signatures, a simple formula is given: if P1 and P2 are public keys that produced valid signatures (r1, s1) and (r2. s2) then
for the public key P1 + P2, the signature (r1+r2, s1+s2) will be valid
however, how? In the context of ed25519 signatures, we have
е = hash(R||P||m),
and
 sG = R + eP

where G is base point
but hash is a non-linear function, so there is a misunderstanding: how will such a sum pass verification if even hashing will not give the desired result? I understand if the signatories agree in advance to use the desired type of hash when producing a signature, but then this does not break down into two separate signatures.

which equations exactly are not relevant? the signature verification equation seems to be correct (if you don't take into account the cofactor in the case of units)
so here I am, seeing that they don't apply, that it won't work. and what do they mean by the linearity of the Schnorr/eddsa signature and by multi-signatures? here is musig/musig2, but the formulas are different there. the sum equation that I gave is encountered quite regularly...
here is Schnorr (with minus variation)
https://medium.com/@qinwen228/multi-signatures-schnorr-signature-and-signature-aggregation-263c9cef212

let me rephrase then: how to correctly construct a collective ed25519 multi-signature (verifiable as a single whole)? what formulas are valid?

I meant: the equations given for combining valid signatures and public keys apply neither to the original Schnorr signature (because one of it's components is a hash), nor EdDSA (for the reason in the question).

Yes, that's how I see it too. Then the question remains: what do they mean by signature linearity, fast verification of a multi-signature as a single whole and how to correctly construct a single multi-signature? exactly like in MuSig, for example, and isn't it simpler?
The equation I gave can be seen quite often... for example here https://youtu.be/TYQ-3VvNCHE?t=1381

here is another place where these formulas are given directly  https://github.com/evenfound/docs-ru/blob/master/schnorr.md

Signature aggregation of your first reference does not work as summarized in the question. What it combines is not valid signatures, but specially prepared pairs with the format of signatures. Further, preparation of the pair supplied by party 1 requires interaction with party 2, and vice versa. Also, that reference mentions choosing $h_1$ and $h_2$ but not using them, so I think we should not look at another reference for what you are trying to adapt to EdDSA/Ed25519.

Well, yes, that's right, the first link says everything as you write. Musig is also a two-round interactive protocol.
I've already figured out the issue. Individual valid ones can be summed up, but the (full) verification of the resulting result is not performed as a single signature verification - after all, you'll have to sum up the individual ones honestly. That is, this is simply a cumulative verification of a system of equations and nothing more, in Bernstein's article this is called batch verification. thank you. it just  sometimes people express themselves not quite correctly about it
